# How to Change File Size to Zero?

Tags: javascript, windows, powershell, batch-file

I have a bunch of files in a Windows folder.  Using a CMD batch file, or JavaScript batch file, or PowerShell, how would you convert the files to zero length files?

Comment: This discussion at SuperUser might help you:
http://superuser.com/questions/299329/resize-a-file-in-command-prompt

Answer (score 3):

Please try this in the command prompt:

```
copy /Y NUL filename >NUL
```

*Remarks*:

`/Y` suppress confirmation of file overwriting

`NUL` is a Windows device file(roughly equivalent to /dev/null in UNIX), which is used to empty the destination file and suppress copying message

Answer (score 3):

Create a batch file and place the below code in the file, This batch file will make all the files to zero in a specific folder.

```
cd <DIRECTORY NAME>
@echo off
pushd %*
for %%j in (*) do type nul > "%%j"
popd
```

hope this might help to you.

Comment: You haven't disclosed that the "specific folder" is supposed to come as the batch file's argument. (Although your using the argument line seems rather unconventional. I mean, why `%*` instead of `%1`?) Anyway, your script seems workable. However, this would probably do just as well: `@for %%j in ("%~1\*") do type nul > "%%j"`.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell for each file in a directory you just need to use :

```
new-Item -path filename -type file -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
dir c:\myfolder  | ? { -not $_.psiscontainer }| % {new-item -Path $_.fullname -ItemType file -force}
```